# A rebase operation is in process in VS 2017

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017, team-explorer

I cannot commit any code through my Visual Studio 2017, but I can commit using other Git tools. There is any way to reset or solve this issue?

This is what I get:

[image]

Comment: Go to the command line and either continue or abort the rebase?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a rebase operation in progress in your repo.  You'll need to either continue it (git rebase --continue) or abort it (git rebase --abort).

Comment: Ok but why with Git Extensions I am able to commit?

Answer (score 1):

Close all open instances of the Visual Studio,

open the command prompt,

go to the location of your local repository with:

```
cd "localRepositoryRootPath"
```

get out of any rebase work that's currently in progress with:

```
git rebase --quit
```

reopen Visual Studio.

It should also resolve the cases where you get this message when you run:
*git rebase --abort*

> warning: could not read '.git/rebase-merge/head-name': No such file or
> directory